# Element is not getting detected in Selenium if loads the table data using 'select number of rows"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Scenario is based on the 2nd column value I need to click on check box lie in first column.
Problem is by default table displays 5 rows of data, in this case the element is getting detected properly and check box works. But if the record is not in displayed 5 rows I have to use the number of item dropdown to load more rows in table in this case the elements has stopped detecting which is available in first 5 rows as well.
So far I checked no change in XPATH and page scrolls a bit so tried using Actions as well to move to the element and click but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things seems to be working after using Actions/ActionChain instead of find_element()